# What can I do with console error : Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, stat 'cypress/integration/cypress...'?

Tags: cypress

I have 20 autotests and open sypress using comand:

```
 ./node_modules/.bin/cypress open
```

And Cypress window is closed. There is Error in the console:

```
Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, stat 'cypress/integration/cypress/integration/cypress/integration/cypress/integration/cypress/integration/cypress/integration/cypress/...'
```

cypress.json:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "https://localhost:3000",
  "video": true,
  "viewportWidth": 1920,
  "viewportHeight": 1024,
  "numTestsKeptInMemory": 0,
  "defaultCommandTimeout" : 15000,
  "testFiles": [
    "1_ID.js",
    "2_ID.js",
    "3_ID.js",
       ...
    "18_ID.js",
    "19_ID.js",
    "20_ID.js",
  ]
}
```

I delete 10 Autotests from the "testFiles" list and Cypress window operate as expected.
What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can check for two things in your testFiles array:

1. Check whether any of the spec file names you added has a typo.
2. Check whether you have added a file name inside the testFiles array but in reality it doesn't exist.

For me personally I faced the same issue on my windows machine and the reason was point 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you have trouble using `testFiles` configuration, try using a parent test instead.

**my-tests.spec.js**

```js
import "1_ID.js";
import "2_ID.js";
import "3_ID.js";
...
import "18_ID.js";
import "19_ID.js";
import "20_ID.js";
```

Run the parent

```js
npx cypress open --spec "my-tests.spec.js"
```